# Artificial Adrenalin

Tags: endocrinology

I was watching Sherlock Holmes - A Game of Shadows yesterday. I saw that he had developed a serum that causes a  person to react like he has been injected with adrenalin.

Watsons's dog fainted, I think, and the moment Holmes injected the dog with this serum, it jumped up and ran away.

So my question is: Is it possible to extract adrenalin, or was it a steroid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to extract adrenaline from the adrenal glands.  This was done in 1901, a [patent was filed](http://www.google.com/patents/US730176), and it was marketed under the name Adrenalin.  It is also known as epinephrine.  It is synthesized nowadays for most uses.